# How to display Yum Local Repo packages in a tree structures based on dependency?

Tags: linux, yum, repository

I have made a local repo by downloading packages and their dependencies using yum with download only option and redirected the all the downloaded packages to a certain folder , then I ran a createrepo command to build repodata. Now the repo is ready and I have used it to download offline, but now I need to display all the packages in that Local Repo in a tree structure based on dependency (which depend on what and so on ... all the chain) for the purpose for documentation.

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of all packages in your local repo:

```
yum --disablerepo "*" --enablerepo "yourlocalrepo" list available
```

Then, use `repoquery` on each package found:

```
repoquery --tree-requires yourpackage
```

If `repoquery` is not on your system, install it via `yum install yum-utils`.